# scala.xml.PrettyPrinter to format shorter node when there is no text in it

Tags: xml, scala, formatting, scala-xml

I use scala.xml.PrettyPrinter to format my XML in Scala. The problem is with nodes without text content. Instead of this:

```
<node></node>
```

I'd prefer to have this:

```
<node />
```

How can I make PrettyPrinter to format it my way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug in scala-xml, but it was fixed in version 1.1.0 on Feb-20-2018.  A new option `minimizeEmpty` was added to `PrettyPrinter`.

To use 1.1.0, add the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.1.0"
)
```

Here's an example of how to make use of the new option in `PrettyPrinter`:

```
val pp = new xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 2, minimizeEmpty = true)
val x = <node><leaf></leaf></node>
println(pp.format(x))
```

This will output:

```
<node>
  <leaf/>
</node>
```

If the Scala compiler, complains:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.xml.PrettyPrinter.<init>(IIZ)V
```

then you need to enable a forked JVM in sbt, so that Scala is using the new version of scala-xml.  Just add the follow to your `build.sbt`:

```
fork := true
```

Previous to scala-xml 1.1.0, the method to create `<node/>`, `leafTag()`, is in the class, but unused. You can fix it like so:

```
import xml._
val p2 = new PrettyPrinter(120, 2) {
  override protected def traverse(node:Node, pscope:NamespaceBinding, ind:Int) = 
    node match {
      case n:Elem if n.child.size == 0 => makeBox(ind, leafTag(n))
      case _ => super.traverse(node, pscope, ind)
    }
}
```

There's no reason to use the override-hack if you can just upgrade to 1.1.0.

Comment: I got the compiler error about a missing constructor today. Thanks!

Comment: @ashawley I'm looking [at the source code](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/v1.1.0/shared/src/main/scala/scala/xml/PrettyPrinter.scala) but I can't see `leafTag` being used anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: @HosamAly No it's not, and you're not the first person to notice that. See https://www.github.com/scala/scala-xml/issues/46